# Anyone have/know of a "universal" string class for C++Builder?

Tags: c++builder

Has anyone built a "universal" string class for C++Builder that manages all of the conversions to/from ASCII and Unicode?

I had a vision of a class that would accept `AnsiString`, `UnicodeString`, `WideString`, `char*`, `wchar_t*`, `std::string`, and `variant` values, and would provide any of those back out. AND the copy constructor has to do a deep copy, not just provide a pointer to the same buffer space (as `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` do).

I figure someone else besides me must have to pass strings to both old interfaces that use `char*` and new ones that use (wide) strings. If you have built, or know of, something you're willing to share, please let me know. Most of the time it's not too big a deal, until I have to pass a `map<std::string, std::string>`, then it starts getting ugly.

We do not, and will not, support any internationalization whatsoever, so I don't need to worry about encoding. I just want a class that will return my little ASCII strings in whatever format makes the compiler happy... sanely.

---

**UPDATE**: to address the comments:

So, `std::map<std::string, std::string>` is ugly, because you can't do:

```
parammap[AnsiString(widekey).c_str()] = AnsiString(widevalue).c_str();
```

Oh no no no. You have to do this:

```
AnsiString akey = widekey;
AnsiString aval = widevalue;
parammap[akey.c_str()] = aval.c_str();
```

The person who originally wrote this code tried to keep it as port-friendly as possible, so he standardized on `char*` for all of the function calls he wrote (circa 2000, it wasn't a bad assumption). Sometimes I was trying to convert everything to `char *`s before I realized that the function was then immediately turning around and converting it back to wide. There are multiple interface layers, and it took me a while to figure out how it all went together.

Add in some creative compiler bugs, where it would get confused, especially when pulling string values out of `Variant`s. In some places, I had to do:

```
String wstr = passedvariant.AsType(varString);
String astr = wstr;
std::string key = astr.c_str();
```

Then life happened, we ended up starting the port over (for the 3rd time. Don't ask), and I finally got smart and wrapped the low-level library in a layer that does all of the conversions, and retooled the middle layers to deal in `String`s, so the application layer can just use `String` except for that `map`. For the `map<string, string>`, I created a function to do the converting, so it was one line in a bunch of places instead of six (the three line conversion above for both key and value).

Lastly, I wasn't actually asking for anyone to make suggestions on how to make my code better. I was asking if anyone had or knew of a universal string class. Our code is the way it is for reasons, and I'm not rewriting all of it to make it prettier. I just wanted not to have to touch so many lines... again. It would have been so much nicer to have the compiler keep track of which format is needed and convert it.

Comment: I find String pretty universal - and std::string good for ascii only situations. So what is your problem exactly. Why is std::map<std::string, std::string> ugly? The C++ STL is rarely (if every) ugly in my experience. Can you give an example of what you are trying to do that you feel you can't easily do?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The RTL string classes know how to convert between each other, so using their various constructors and assignment operators is trivial, and they all support both `char*` and `wchar_t*` too. The C++ string classes, not so much, though since you are dealing with only ASCII then it is possible to convert between `std::string` and `std::wstring` without too much trouble. But in general, when dealing with standard C++ code then use the C++ string classes, and when dealing with RTL code then use the RTL string classes, and perform conversions between them as needed when crossing library boundaries.

Comment: *I* only need ascii. VCL, however deals in wide strings.  Yes, they convert easily, but I have hundreds of thousands lines of code and keeping track of when I have to switch to ascii-mode sometimes gets a little dicey. And it's cumbersome. You'd think it wouldn't be that big of a deal. But it get's surprisingly ugly at times.

Comment: @KarenCate without actual examples of what you consider to be "dicey" or "ugly", we can't really help you make the code better. What percentage of your code deals with the VCL, and what percentage is just standard C++? You should stick with a single string type for as much work as you can do with it, only converting to other string types when absolutely necessary. The VCL's native string type is `System::String`, which is `UnicodeString` in CB2009+. Just because you are only dealing with the ASCII subset of Unicode doesn't mean you should ignore Unicode completely.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added more information to the original post. It would be too hard to read in a comment. See above.

Comment: @KarenCate I'm voting to close the question. Asking for recommendations for third-party libraries is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. I told you that 1 1/2 year ago.  Your update provides nothing to change that.

Comment: @KarenCate And FYI, `parammap[AnsiString(widekey).c_str()] = AnsiString(widevalue).c_str();` works just fine with `std::string` for the key/value types, you *do not* need to save the strings into local `AnsiString` variables first, as you claim. But your `Variant` example is wrong, since `std::string key = astr.c_str()` won't compile as `astr` is a `UnicodeString` not `AnsiString`. You meant to write `AnsiString astr = wstr;`, but then you may as well just use `std::string key = AnsiString(passedvariant).c_str();` the end result will be the same.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry for the typo's, I was kind of typing off the top of my head, and not from actual code examples. As for `parammap[AnsiString(widekey).c_str()] = AnsiString(widevalue).c_str();`, I *was* getting incorrect behavior with this. If you're saying it works then that hopefully means it has been fixed since the version I am using, which is XE7.  No worries about closing the question. Thank you so much for all the help you've provided this community. At least one of us really appreciates it, even if we might sound testy in text. :)

Comment: @KarenCate I don't have XE7 so I can't check this, but there should be **no functional difference** between `parammap[AnsiString(widekey).c_str()] = AnsiString(widevalue).c_str();` vs `AnsiString akey = widekey; AnsiString aval = widevalue; parammap[akey.c_str()] = aval.c_str();` as both are constructing `std::string` objects from `const char*` pointers. The only difference would be in the lifetimes of the `AnsiString` objects, but the `map` doesn't care about those since the `std::string` objects are making copies of the `char` data.